# Unable to get via @wire the role of the current user in salesforce experience site

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, experience-cloud

```javascript
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: currentUserId, optionalFields: ['User.Profile.Name', 'User.AccountId', 'User.Account.Name','User.UserRole.Name'] })
    userData({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('user data ====> ', data);
```

Here you can see that I'm requesting various fields with @wire next I get them in the console.log.

Except for the role that never shows up.

I precise that the current user in the community site is assigned a role. (I think that's always the case.)

If I set the field in field and not optional field like this:

```javascript
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: currentUserId, fields : ['User.UserRole.Name']  })
```

I get this error :

```json
{
    "status":400,
    "body": {
        "message": "INVALID_FIELD:
                    SELECT LastModifiedDate, UserRole.Name, Id, LastModifiedById
                    ERROR at Row:1:Column:26
                    Didn't understand relationship 'UserRole' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",
        "statusCode":400,
        "errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"
    },
    "headers":{}
}
```

Do someone know if there is a way to get the current user role in experience cloud?

Comment: How is currentUserId being set? What happens if you make it reactive? Are the other fields showing up?

Comment: The currentUserId is set like this :
import currentUserId from '@salesforce/user/Id';
What do you mean by make it reactive if I may @sfdcfox?
Yes the Profile and the Account.Name also.
I was wondering if it is because of the fact the role for a community user is specialy created but I don't know.

Comment: Hmm, no, that's not the problem. What happens if you move the field from optionalFields to just fields? Do you get an error?

Comment: yes indeed  @sfdcfox:

error ====>  {"status":400,"body":{"message":"INVALID_FIELD: \nProfile.LastModifiedById, Profile.Id, Profile.Name, UserRole.Name, Id, Profile.SystemModstamp\n                                                    ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:104\nDidn't understand relationship 'UserRole' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"},"headers":{}}

Comment: That suggests that the user can't view the UserRole object, or that field. I think it's due to the "View Roles and Role Hierarchy" permission, which I don't think you can enable for such a user. Check the user's profile permissions. I guess you could probably use Contact.Account.Name as a close alternative.